# What does "reputee" mean?

Tags: meaning

I wonder what does the word "reputee" mean? What is the meaning?

Comment: you'll need to provide some context.  Do you have a link to the word in a complete sentence, or can you type it in here?

Comment: I think this question would be just too localised, even if OP did supply some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very rare term in English.  Searching [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=reputee&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=reputee&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=MdVvT5_nFsGL0QHN343eBg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=63a84ff2387071ab&biw=1920&bih=955) yields many results, but all in French.  Only [one result](http://books.google.com/books?ei=ndRvT-nkH6r40gG_jqHhBg&id=Jb0voFUa2FAC&dq=%22reputee%22&q=repu-tee#v=snippet&q=repu-tee&f=false) I saw was in English (*Cardozo: A Study in Reputation*), and in the whole book, the word occurred only three times (link has all three listed):

[image]

In this case, it appears to mean *one whose reputation is being analyzed*.